# Is there a loop in .xml view in Android development? To render multiple same elements

Tags: android, angular, ngfor

Is there something similar like `*ngFor` in android 2+, for Android development in .xml layout?

For example:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
 <button>{{ item.name }}</button>
</div>
```

I need this:

```
<Button
  android:id = "@+id/btn1">
</Button>
<Button
  android:id = "@+id/btn2">
</Button>
<Button
  android:id = "@+id/btn3">
</Button>
<Button
  android:id = "@+id/btn4">
</Button>
```

**I am interested is there a way in android development .xml view to repeat equal elements, or the only way is to add them programatically?**